# how do I build a tree hierarchy from a list in groovy using recursive closure?

Tags: grails, groovy, closures

I defined the recursive domain class in grails:

```
class Work {

  String code
  String title
  String description
  static hasMany = [subWorks:Work]
  static mappedBy = [subWorks: 'parentWork']

  Work getRootWork(){
    if(parentWork) return parentWork.getRootWork()
      else return this
  }

  boolean isLeafWork(){
    return subWorks.isEmpty()
  }

  boolean isRootWork(){
    return !parentWork
  }
```

I have a list of Works, but the hierarchy structure is not built yet. The structure looks like:

```
def works = [new Work(code:'A', title:'TitleA'), 
    new Work(code:'B', title:'TitleB'), 
    new Work(code:'A.1', title:'Titile A.1'), 
    new Work(code:'B.1', title:'Title B.1'),
    new Work(code:'B.2', title:'Title B.2'),
    new Work(code:'B.3', title:'Title B.3'), 
    new Work(code:'B.2.2', title:'Title B.2.2'),
    new Work(code:'B.2.3', title:'Title B.2.3'),
    new Work(code:'A.1.1', title:'Title A.1.1'),
    new Work(code:'A.1.2', title:'Title A.1.2'),]
```

What I need is to build the hierarchical relationship among these works, based on the code hinted. e.g. A.1 is the first child work of A; B.1.1 is the first child of B.1 work, whose parent is B work. I know that Groovy supports recursive closures to build this kind of hierarchical structure. How do I achieve my goal using Groovy recursive closure, such as the JN2515 Fibonacci number example, in Groovy official documentation?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this...?

```
def root = new Work(code:'*', title:'ROOT')

def build 

build = { p, list ->
  list.groupBy{it.code.split('\\.').first()}.each{ el, sublist ->
    el = sublist[0]        
    el.parentWork = p
    if(sublist.size()>1){
        build(el, sublist[1..-1] )
    }
  }

}
build(root, works.sort{it.code.length()})
```

if I'm not in error even in this anonim form may work

```
def root = new Work(code:'*', title:'ROOT')

{ p, list ->
  list.groupBy{it.code.split('\\.').first()}.each{ el, sublist ->
    el = sublist[0]        
    el.parentWork = p
    if(sublist.size()>1){
      call(el, sublist[1..-1] )
    }
  }

}(root, works.sort{it.code.length()})
```

Comment: Many thanks for the enlightened code. The above code works for the sample list: works. What if I need A.1.2 work belong to A.1; A.2.2 work is the second child of A.2? Just slightly edit my question.

Comment: If you want subWorks in an ordered fashion you have to change your data structure. Look here, http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps. I think you want to use SortedSet and implement compareTo method in the Work class.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit rusty with Grails, but i seem to remember that it managed mapped collections in an intelligent way, such that if you do: `work1.parentWork = work2` then `work1 in work2.subWorks` will verify. If that's the case, all you need to do is set the `parentWork` for every work, and you don't need to do any complicated computation for this: the parent work of `X.Y.Z` will be `X.Y`, and the parent work of `X` will be none:

```
def works = [new Work(code:'A', title:'TitleA'),
    new Work(code:'B', title:'TitleB'),
    new Work(code:'A.1', title:'Titile A.1'),
    new Work(code:'B.1', title:'Title B.1'),
    new Work(code:'A.1.1', title:'Title A.1.1')]

def worksByCode = works.collectEntries { [it.code, it] }

works.each {
    if (it.code.contains('.')) {
        def parentCode = it.code[0..it.code.lastIndexOf('.') - 1]
        it.parentWork = worksByCode[parentCode]
    }
}
```